# Active record reset database connection issues - ActiveRecord::Connection.clear_active_connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can some body explain me what does these two function exactly do, i am not able to understand it through rails api.

```
  ActiveRecord::Connection.clear_active_connections!
  ActiveRecord::Connection.clear_all_connections!()
```

I am working on an application, in which i have to make dynamic db connection. 
Do i need to put these lines before making a new connection.
When i make a new connection what happens to old connection, since i do not remove it explicitly, does this happens automatically ?

Answer (score 4):

First off, I think you want `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`

I'm looking at these issues now. As best I can tell `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` will drop all prior connections from the pool and only use the new connection.

I'm running into issues when I'm swapping back and forth and changing connections both at the `ActiveRecord::Base` level and at the individual model level (i.e. `User.establish_connection`. Under certain circumstances, I find that if I establish a connection on the model, then establish a connection on `ActiveRecord::Base` (intending to also use the new connection on the model), the model will retain the connection.

To wit:

```
$ ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:host]
-> main
$ User.connection_config[:host]
-> main

$ User.establish_connection :blah
$ User.connection_config[:host]
-> blah
$ ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:host]
-> main

$ ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :blah
$ User.connection_config[:host]
-> blah
$ ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:host]
-> blah

$ ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :main
$ User.connection_config[:host]
-> blah
$ ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:host]
-> main
```

The important point to note here is that, since you've established the connection on the `User` model explicitly, `ActiveRecord` knows to use a different connection pool than that used for the other children of `ActiveRecord::Base`; thus, when you switch the `ActiveRecord::Base` connection back, it doesn't switch *all* models, just the ones sharing the main connection pool.

Here's the `ConnectionHandler` doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionHandler.html